Docker Swarm macvlan network Setup for Static IPs Fails with "Gateway Address Already in Use"
We’re working on a setup where specific containers in Docker Swarm need to have static IP addresses. To achieve this, we’re using macvlan networks, alongside HAProxy for load balancing across these services.
Our approach involves creating a unique macvlan network for each service as follows:
Config-Only Network Creation (on all Swarm servers):
docker network create -d macvlan --config-only --subnet=192.168.110.0/24 --gateway=192.168.110.1 --ip-range=192.168.110.12/32 parent=ens193 app01

Swarm Network Creation (on manager):
docker network create -d macvlan --scope swarm --config-from app01 swarm_app01

For new applications, we add additional virtual network adapters (e.g., ens224) and assign new networks with static IPs.
The issue is that, after successfully setting up and running four IPs and networks, any attempt to create a fifth network now results in the following error:
css
Copy code
failed to allocate gateway (192.168.110.1): address already in use
We're running Docker version 27.1.2 (build d01f265).
Is anyone familiar with this error, or does anyone have alternative suggestions for assigning static IPs to services within a Docker Swarm? Any help or insight would be appreciated!
